# Shape.CopyPicture fails (Error 1004) when Format:=xlBitmap

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am attempting to copy a shape group which contains some charts as a high resolution picture. To achieve the high resolution, I use the options `Appearance:=xlPrinter` and `Format:=xlBitmap`.

> Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

The code I am using to do this is below

```
ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")).Group.Name = "temp_group"
With ws.Shapes("temp_group")
    .CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlBitmap
    .Ungroup
End With
```

If I just remove the `Format:=xlBitmap` or change it to `Format:=xlPicture`, it works fine. The MSDN help shows `xlBitmap` as an option and I have tried just using 2 but that gives the same error.

If I try the same thing on a single chart, it works just fine.

```
ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlBitmap
```

What is the best way to copy multiple charts as a high resolution picture? I would like to avoid saving them because I need to copy/paste multiple groups of up to 30 charts for exporting to OneNote.

Edit:

After some additional testing, it turns out that I can use `xlBitmap` if the appearance option is set to `xlScreen` instead of `xlPrinter`. However, the resolution is still pretty terrible. This is very frustrating since just copy/pasting these same charts manually gives very nice clear pictures but for some reason VBA just ruins it. VBA is required though since this would be a very time consuming process otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

shape.copypicture work's fine in excel 2016. The error is in office 360.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem in my app. Here is the solution:

- If you want to copy an object of type MsoShapeType.msoChart or MsoShapeType.msoPicture do this trick:

> ```
> shape.ScaleHeight(2.5f, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
> shape.ScaleWidth(2.5f, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
> shape.Copy();
> shape.CopyPicture(Excel.XlPictureAppearance.xlScreen, Excel.XlCopyPictureFormat.xlPicture);
> shape.ScaleHeight(0.4f, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
> shape.ScaleWidth(0.4f, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
> ```

where `shape` is of course your object.

First, you need to scale up the object (scaling is loseless up to orginal size of the image or maximum size of the chart, which is just 400% zooming). Then, you use CopyPicture() method with mentioned parameters, preceed with Copy()*.The last thing to do is to scale down (or not, if you won't save this sheet) the object.

*Copy() is used here to eliminate common and random error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): CopyPicture method of range class failed

If you open any Excel sheet, you will see some copy configurations:
[link, because I can't add images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RH9le.png)

- Common copy is just (xlScreen, xlBitmap);
- Good quality copy is xlScreen, xlPicture) and, depending on installed printer driver, (xlPrinter) and (xlPrinter, xlPicture);

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. After pasting, the pictures were definitely bigger but not any better resolution. It also doesn't appear that you are doing this in VBA since I get an error if I add semicolons at the end of lines and the "f" after the number results in an error as well.